# Postgres não aceita comandos. Erro "Invalid binary"

Tags: postgresql, binary

Boa tarde Pessoal. Estou instalando o Postgres e ao tentar criar o banco de dados pela interface de linha de comando, o postgres me da a seguinte mensagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no caso ele não está aceitando nenhum comando. Na print eu dei o seguinte comando:  createdb -E SQL_ASCII -T template0 "nome do bd" "nome do usuario do db"

Eu realmente não sei mais o que fazer. pois já testei outras versões do postgres 9.5 e o erro permanece. estou tentando o Postgres 9.5 64 bits baixado direto do site do Postgres

*Edit: Eu tive o mesmo problema em outros 2 computadores com essa versão do postgres 64 bits. A versão 32 bits funciona sem problema algum. Pensei que fosse incompatibilidade com o windows, iso do windows com problema ou algo do tipo mas estes testes já foram feitos. O engraçado é que nós sempre usamos estes executáveis e de repente este problema começou ocorrer. Pensávamos que fosse arquivo infectado por vírus mas baixamos vários executáveis do site do postgres e o erro persiste.

Comment: Não poderia realizar esse processo pelo pgadmin? Como você está utilizando Windows acredito que terá menos problemas.

Comment: Tentei abrir o PG admin e ele dá a seguinte mensagem de erro "PostgreSQL tools parou de funcionar"

Comment: Eu fiz algum procedimento na minha própria base que já tem o postgresql instalado funcionando normalmente, e agora qualquer comando que eu insiro pela interface de linha de comando, ele da essa mesma mensagem "invalid binary "c:/arquivos de programas/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql.exe "